# Why curvature operator is the infinitesimal holonomy rotation

Tags: riemannian-geometry

First picture below is from Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow. I don't understand the red line.

I read the holonomy in Wiki,  I understand the second picture which is from Wiki. But I fail to know the strict definition of holonomy.

I want to know  why $R(X,Y)$ is the infinitesimal holonomy rotation  from second picture ? And why it leads a natural definition of curvature operator ?

PS: $Rm(X,Y,W,Z)= \langle R(X,Y)W,Z\rangle$

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: See https://cims.nyu.edu/~yangd/papers/holonomy.pdf